# Error:Could not find filename.apk

Tags: android

when i run the emulator it give the error in console . Could not find filename.apk.
and i installed the plugins ADT 11.0.what should now i do.please help me. 
thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to export it (right click on the project, export signed application) and to upload manually using adb (./adb install filename.apk)